# Different behavior for select statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am getting two different behaviors by select statement in MS SQL

```
create table #alpha3 (names varchar(max))
insert into #alpha3 values ('a'), ('aa')
declare @txt varchar(max)
select top 10 @txt = concat(@txt, names, ' ') from #alpha3
select @txt;
```

So in the above query, the select statement is cycling through the values from the **names** column. And that way we can store the values in variable as a string

For the below recursive query however

```
with cte as 
( select cast('aa' as varchar(max)) as names, 0 as num 
  union all 
  select cast (names + 'a' as varchar(max)), num+1 from cte
  where num<10 
  ) 
select * from cte
```

In the above case however, the select statement just is taking the last value from the last row in the column and returning it to be unioned with the anchor table/statement. So it is not cycling through all the values in the column as it did in the top query.

The select statement in below query is again having the same behavior as the top query:

```
create table #beta (names varchar(max))
insert into #beta values ('a'), ('aa')

select * from (
select * from #beta
union all 
select * from #beta) as aa
```

Can someone please tell why is the select statement acting differently in the recursive query?

Comment: Different statement different behavior. Why bother?

Comment: Hey Meyssam. So I was expecting the recursive query to add the 'a' to all the rows in the cte.

Comment: And then in the next loop to add it to all the rows again and union it to the original table

Comment: If select is giving different behavior in different places it becomes hard to model the queries. Doesn't it ?

Comment: These are simply completely different queries, and they all give different results, but none of them are acting in a way contrary to their expected semantics. If there's a problem with the model, it would be your own mental model that they should somehow be equivalent. What is the actual *result* you're after? Why did you think a recursive query was necessary or useful?

Comment: Hey Jeroen. So I am just learning SQL. And as per my understanding the select statement returns/cycles-through the values in a column. Which is being depicted in the top and bottom query. But in the recursive query, it was not showing that behavior. So it was confusing if select shows multiple behavior or is there something else in play here.

Comment: `SELECT .. FROM` operates on every row in the set, but a recursive query is quite different because it builds a new set entirely (through recursion). It is not the case that a recursive query is equivalent to a simple `SELECT` in the way that a recursive algorithm would be equivalent to a sequential one, and you can do things with recursive queries that would be impossible with simple `SELECT`s (assuming you didn't pre-build tables). Your first query operates on two rows, your third query operates on four rows (2 + 2), but your second one *generates* 11 rows.

Comment: Thank you for this Jeroen. Can you recommend some reading material regarding this as to how the select works in the recursive. I have been trying to find it online but maybe I am not using the right terminology to search

Comment: The basic construct is known as a recursive CTE (common table expression). Under this name plenty of material is available, though I have no specific resources to recommend.